# Angularfire - How to apply 'where' conditions with snapshotChanges()

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am rather new to angular & firebase and current using the angular/fire to retrieve the collections with the condition as per below in the service;

**service.ts**

```
get posts() {
  return this.afs
          .collection<Todo>('posts', ref => {
            let query:
              | firebase.firestore.CollectionReference
              | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;

            query = query.where('posted', '==', true);

            return query;
          })
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(action =>
              action.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data();
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              }),
            ),
          );
}
```

In the component I am subscribing to the observable to retrieve the posts with "posted" field equals **true**. The below is working as expected and only the "posted" posts are being logged.

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.posts.subscribe(posts => {
      console.log(posts);
    })
}
```

But, when adding the post with the "posted" field equals to **false**, this post is also being logged in the console.

Partially it makes sense to me, since the collection is updated and the component is subscribed to it, resulting in an update.

However, my expectations was event if the collections has changed, it will still have the conditions applied & filter out again.

Thank you all for helping out a newbie

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Your component is initialized only once (`ngOnInit()` is run only once) with the code you're showing, and it logs documents that have `'posted'` == `false`? Or you've run this twice (initialized the component twice)? If your app is expected to subscribe to `snapshotChanges()` multiple times, you should unsubscribe as well (you usually subscribe in `ngOnInit()` and unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy()`. If all you need to do is show your items in a template, you don't need to subscribe manually, you can use the `async` pipe, so that subscriptions are handled automatically.

Comment: I also find it very convenient to add `id` as a field in every document and use `valueChanges()` instead of `snapshotChanges()`, but this is irrelevant.

Comment: @Stratubas, I am using a modal to add the post & the main component with the list of posts never being reinitialized/ destroyed (still having a destroy & unsubscribe implemented) and so it's always listening to the changes when the item is added with the 'posted' == true, at least that was my expectation.

Comment: Try opening another browser tab and adding a *posted = false* post from that tab. Is it logged in the first tab? What if you add it manually using firebase console? Still logged?

Comment: @Stratubas, I tried your suggestion and instead of manually subscribing, I am using async pipe and it is working as expected. Thank you very much for your help :) Will have to learn more about observables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `angularfire2` and `firebase` too well but you can take advantage of the `map` operator and `filter` operator of array maybe.

Try:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.posts.pipe(
      map(posts => posts.filter(post => post.posted)),
    ).subscribe(posts => {
      console.log(posts);
    })
}
```

Comment: yeah, it is a possible things to do, however it seems to me (I am not sure), that this approach will cause a duplicate logic, which are 
(1) Filtering is done by firebase on (2) Filtering is done by application.
Meaning that in the end I am still getting a full set of data from firebase (server) which I would like to avoid. If it's only a few records, than it's no problem, but if it's 10k+ it sounds somehow wrong way to do so.

Comment: I have the same concerns as you but like I said I don't know those technologies that well :/